# The most probable score in Microsoft Spider Solitaire

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

My dad plays a lot of [Spider Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Spider_Solitaire) on his computer. He told me he noticed he solved it very often in $299$ moves.

I'm not a mathematician, but I think someone must have thought of the mathematics behind this game. In particular, I'm curious if anyone calculated the most probable score and if it's close to $299$.

Unlike normal Solitaire, the Microsoft version has $104$ cards for the advanced level, which is what I'm referring to.

Comment: There is, amazingly, a master's thesis about Spider Solitaire. Look for **How Many Games of Spider Solitaire are Winnable?** by Mark Weisser (Wesleyan University, 2012); I am unable to get a direct link to the PDF.

Comment: On Klondike Solitaire: [Solitaire: Man Versus Machine](http://web.stanford.edu/~bvr/pubs/solitaire.pdf).